# sql - insert record on table2 to table 1 with conditions

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables on mysql database

what they have in common is they both have a city and state field with both being populated with records.

but table2 has a county field while table 1 has none. Where table2 records covers ALL the states and table1 has 1 particular state.

I need to populate table1 county field upon successfully matching city and state fields.

Please help!

Comment: Please show us the Table schemas, and rather tell us if you wish to UPDATE existing records, or INSERT new ones

Answer (score 0):

First of all add column "country" in table1, then

> update table1 a,table2 b
>   set a.country=b.country
>   where a.city=b.city and a.state=b.state